# Does modal popup extender need update panel?

Tags: ajax, updatepanel, modalpopupextender

Is it necessary that we shud use modal popup extender inside an update panel ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can use it without an UpdatePanel, but you still need a ScriptManager.